# How to delete all characters up to and including a specified character in a text file?

Tags: json, bash, sed

Quick sed question

In a text file how do I remove all characters up to and including the first '[' found in the entire file and nothing else?

I tried

`sed "s/^[^\[]*\[//" example.json`

but it's stripping out all text on every line.

Alternately,

I have a set of files that are sets of JSON documents. I am trying to import them into elasticsearch, but the first document in the file is an informational document with a non-standard layout that messes up the importing of the rest of the documents. I'm trying to get rid of the first document so the subsequent documents can load properly.

Here is the document:

https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2014-01-01&endtime=2014-01-02

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: GNU sed: `sed -z 's/^[^[]*\[//' example.json > example.out.json`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/uiL9bw)

Comment: POSIX sed: `sed '/^[^\[]*\[/!d;s///;:1;n;b1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anything other than a simple `s/old/new` on individual strings just use awk. This will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
awk 'sub(/[^[]*\[/,""){f=1} f' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I used two sed commands to achieve the task to "remove all characters up to and including the first '[' found"

```
sed -n '/\[/,$p' example.json | sed -r '1 s/[^\[]*\[(.*)/\1/'
```